# Winform / Group Box?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I drew a Group Box around a bunch of controls cause I wanted to the Box, meanwhile all the controls are glued to the Group Box. How can I remove the Group Box without removing the Controls?

Comment: When do you want to do that? **Design** time or **Run** time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the controls inside the group box and move them out of it. And then delete the group box...

Comment: This is not possible always as, when the groupbox is almost large as the whole window, we can move the contents out of it. Even by largening the window to the highest limit I could not get all the contents out